# intersection of analytic set : codimension?

Tags: complex-analysis

****Hello.** Let $A$ and $B$ be analytic sets of pure dimension in an analytic set X of $\mathbb{C }^{n}$. Suppose $A$ is a local complete intersection (i.e. for every point $a$ of $A$, there exists $\Omega$ an open neighbourhood of $a$ such that  $A \cap \Omega = \{x \in \Omega | f_{1}(x) = ... = f_{p}(x) = 0\}$ where $f_{i}$ are holomorphs distincts and $p = codim_{X}(A)$).
**Then, if $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$ why do we have $codim_{X}(A \cap B) \leq codim_{X}(A) + codim_{X}(B)$?****

I tried to solve this by induction on $dim(A)$; here is the proof I first made (I realised afterwards the step $*$ is false). It's trivial if $dim(A) = 1$. Then, if $dim(A) > 1$, I choose $a \in A \cap B$ and I wright $A \cap \Omega = \{x \in \Omega | f_{1}(x) = ... = f_{p}(x) = 0\}$ where $f_{i}$ are holomorph distincts and $p = codim_{X}(A)$ and $B \cap \Omega = \{x \in \Omega | g_{1}(x) = ... = g_{p'}(x) = 0\}$ where $g_{i}$ are holomorph and distincts. Since the problem is located in $a$, we will wright $dim_{a} = dim$ and the same for $codim$. Notice that I have $p' \leq codim_{X}(B) $. We can wright $A \cap B \cap \Omega = \{x \in \Omega | g_{1}(x) = ... = g_{p''}(x) = f_{1}(x) = ... = f_{p}(x) = 0\}$ where $p'' \leq p'$ is such that there is no repetition between $g_{j}$ and $f_{i}$. Now let's have a look at : $A' := \{x \in \Omega | g_{p''}(x) = f_{1}(x) = ... = f_{p}(x) = 0\} \subset A$. We wright $B' := \{x \in \Omega | g_{1}(x) = ... = g_{p''-1}(x) = 0\}$. By looking$*$ the local irreductible components of $A$( which are all of dimensions $dim(A)$ since $A$ is of pure dimension) in $a$ we have $A'$ is of dimension $dim(A) - 1$ so of codimension $codim_{X}(A) + 1$. Thus, $A'$ is a local complete intersection and so by induction $codim_{X}(A \cap B) = codim_{X}(A' \cap B') \leq codim_{X}(A') + codim_{X}(B') = codim_{X}(A) + 1 + codim_{X}(B')$. But $1 + codim_{X}(B')$ doesn't necessary have to be $\leq codim_{X}(B)$ (imagine $B$ is an irreductible component of $B'$ in $a$).

$*$Here I use the (6.2) Theorem page 106 of this curse [https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~demailly/manuscripts/agbook.pdf](https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/%7Edemailly/manuscripts/agbook.pdf) . But it dosen't work since $g_{p''}$ can be constant on some irreductible components of $A$ in $a$.

Thank you for your help.

I wish you a good day.

Comment: Please use the [basic tutorial and quick reference guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and the [Meta Read](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and enhance your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it : in the case where $A \cap B \subset B_{sing}$, I choose $a \in (A \cap B)_{reg}$ (which it's always possible since this set is dense in $A \cap B$) and I suppose $codim_{X, a}(A \cap B) > codim_{X, a}(A) + codim_{X, a}(B)$. Then, by corolary $(4.33)$ we know that $\mathcal{J}_{A \cap B, a}$ is generated by at least $codim_{X, a}(A) + codim_{X, a}(B) + 2$ elements as a $\mathcal{O}_{B, a}$ module which is absurde because $\mathcal{J}_{A \cap B, a}$ (which is prime since $A\cap B$ is regular in $a$) is generated as a $\mathcal{O}_{a}(\mathbb{C}^{n})$ (and so as a $\mathcal{O}_{B, a}$ module) by $codim_{X, a}(A) + codim_{X, a}(B)$ elements by using and applying the (6.3) Theorem page 106 to  $A \cap B \cap \Omega = \{x \in \Omega | g_{1}(x) = ... = g_{p''}(x) = f_{1}(x) = ... = f_{p}(x) = 0\}$.

Answer (score 0):

I add this : my problem is the exercise 11.11. page 128 of this book : https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/%7Edemailly/manuscripts/agbook.pdf . The dimension is defined page 98 of this same curse and the codimension in $X$ of $A$ at a point $a \in A$ is define by $codim_{X, a}(A) := dim_{a}X - dim_{a}A$. For my background, I readed the two first chapters of the book I link (and I made the most exercises of those two chapters except the one I'm asking the question for). I'm reading at complex geometry and I also have the agregation.

I hope it enhances the question (I tried to respect the meta read). I'm french so sorry for the eventuals mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

I simplified the problem : if $a$ is choose regular in $B$ (i.e. $B$ is a manifold in an neighbourhood of $a$), then the last inequality hold. However, I still don't know what to do in the case where $A \cap B_{reg} = \emptyset$. All your suggestions are welcomed.

Perhaps (4.33) Corollary page 102 can help? I don't know.